# how to update a package in ubuntu 10.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, redhat, installation

So I don't have much server experience so please bear with me...

I working on a system with ubuntu 10.04 and have installed a program called pdftk. When I ran apt-get install pdftk, it successfully installed version 1.41, but this is a versions from pre 2010 and there is a bug in one of the functions. I am trying to update to 2.02 but don't know the commands to run to update this.

The commands for installing it on 1.41 on redhat/centOS are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146766/how-do-i-install-pdftk-on-my-server?rq=1) and the company's commands for installing 2.02 are [here](https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/install-pdftk-on-redhat-or-centos/)

Maybe one of you guys can combine the two links with your knowledge of ubuntu to guide me in the right direction. I would offer a bounty with this if I could !

Sincere thanks for any help. It is greatly appreciated.

Here is my sources.list:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid main restricted universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid main restricted universe

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates main restricted universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates main restricted universe

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security main restricted universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security main restricted universe
```

Comment: Have you seen this [answer about updating a single package](http://askubuntu.com/questions/44122/how-to-upgrade-a-single-package-using-apt-get) with `apt-get`?  If that did not install an updated package there could be other dependencies, or you may not be connected to the correct repositories.  Repos need to be added the same way that the update repos need to be added in RHEL for yum to be able to access new packages

Comment: it says it's already at the newest version.  Does this mean it's not compatible with the newest versions or someone just hasn't notified ubuntu of the latest version?

Comment: when I installed it on ubuntu 14.04, the proper version was installed

Comment: It is possible that it is not aware of any newer versions because apt-get cannot access any repositories that have newer version.  Can you post the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list `? also check out this link about [adding repositories](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu)

Comment: That makes sense, surely. I added my sources.list.

Comment: You should consider upgrading to a newer Ubuntu version: even the server version of 10.04 has reached its EOL at the end of April.

Comment: Have you tried `apt-get install pdftk=2.02-2` to specify the version? and/or `apt-cache showpkg pdftk` to show the different versions available?

Comment: If you are comfortable upgrading the server to a newer version, that would probably be the best way to proceed, as @n.st mentioned 10.04 has been EOL'd

Comment: thanks a lot for the suggestions, I will definitely try both of those.

Comment: I get 1.41+dfsg-7 - libc6 (2 2.4) libgcc1 (2 1:4.1.1) libgcj10 (2 4.4) libstdc++6 (2 4.4.0) libgcj-bc (2 4.4~) libgcj-bc (3 4.5~) libitext-java-gcj (2 2.1.7-1~) libitext-java-gcj (1 2.1.7++) libitext-java (0 (null)) libbcprov-java (0 (null)) libbcmail-java (0 (null)) xpdf-utils (0 (null))

Comment: and the pdftk=2.02-2 (I tried a bunch of other versions) returns E: Version '2.01' for 'pdftk' was not found

Comment: thanks for the help though. I will look into the ubuntu upgrade.